# What happens when you Request on Massdrop?

Tags: massdrop

I am trying to get an idea of how Massdrop works.

What really happens when you `Request` on [Massdrop](https://www.massdrop.com/)? If you go for instance to a `Group buy` for a product where `The drop has ended` and the following message is displayed:

> Want to bring it back? Request it! After 200 requests, we’ll contact the vendor to re-launch the drop.

So what happens when I click on `Request`? Does this legally bind me to purchase the item if the 200 threshold has been reached, and price negotiations with the manufacturer were successful? Or is it simply a means to signal intent for the product, but still leaves me free to choose whether to buy it or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter. It is simply used to get a rough idea of how many people are interested in it. Once there are 200 requests, you get an email from Massdrop informing you that you can now purchase the product.